# Get current contact id?

Tags: api

I display the summary page for a civicrm contact and I need to get the current contact id. Is there any built in function for that?

I have this code where I explicitly refer to the civicrm id 4. Instead of doing that I would like to refer to the current civicrm contact.

```
$contact_id = 4;
$custom_name = array("custom_2","custom_3","custom_6","custom_7");
$params = array(
        'return' => $custom_name,
        'version' => 3,
        'id' => $contact_id,
);

$result = civicrm_api( 'contact','get',$params );
```

Comment: Related question asks if there's an API method to do the same: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10849/how-to-get-contact-id-of-logged-in-user-in-js-api

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on the contact summary screen, then the contact id is always `$_GET['cid']`. To give yourself peace-of-mind about using raw input, cast it to an integer.

```
$contactId = (int) $_GET['cid'];
```

Comment: You could also do this with    `$contactId = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('cid', 'Positive');`

Comment: I think Erik's should be a separate answer and the only correct one. Coleman, really!

Answer (score 18):

The answer davejenx is correct but [no longer considered best practice](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19028).  Instead use:

```
CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->getLoggedInContactID();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Which Civi versions implement this method?

Comment: It's in 4.4+, maybe earlier versions too?

Comment: I have some custom code using this and it recently stopped working (it's returning 0). I've converted to using the UFMatch api call to fix. This is as of 5.19.4 with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 7):

*Edit:* The techniques below get the *logged-in user's* contact id. However the questioner has clarified that this isn't what they meant by "the current contact id". I'll leave this answer in place in case it's useful to someone else who misunderstood the question.
Here's a simple way:

```
CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->getLoggedInContactID();
```

The above (for which thanks to Jon G) replaces this older technique:

```
$session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton();
$contact_id = $session->get('userID');
```

You can also do it by getting the user id from the CMS (Drupal / Wordpress / Joomla), then using the CiviCRM API to get that user's UFMatch record, which gives you the contact id.

Comment: I use wordpress. Do you know how to return the current contact_id in wordpress?

Comment: This will return MY wordpress username's ID but I need the currently displayed contact's civicrm ID :)

Comment: Like davejenx said: use the Civi API UFMatch Get (with uf_id = the wordpress username's id), it will return you the contact_id.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. In that case, see Coleman's answer.

Comment: This is no longer considered best practice, see my answer.