# How to get contact id of logged-in user in JS API

Tags: api, javascript, angular

Sorry if I'm being thick here, but I've looked and looked. Is there an API call to get the contact id of the logged-in user?

What I need to do is check whether an activity has been authored by the logged in user (in order to show or hide an edit button, in an angular extension).

If there is a way of restricting people from editing (but not from viewing) CiviCase activities that weren't created by them, that would be even better, but I fear it will be easier to do the above.

Cheers

Comment: This would be useful! Have you seen `checkPerm()` function? It might not be fine-grained enough for your needs, but ... Check eg `ang/crmMailing/EditMailingCtrl.js` and `ang/crmMailing/EditMailingCtrl/workflow.html`. It seems to read `CRM.permissions` which is populated on page load?

Answer (score 3):

In case of an angular page use something like

```
function myext_civicrm_angularModules(&$angularModule) {
  [...]
  $session =& CRM_Core_Session::singleton();
  drupal_add_js(array('CurrentCiviUid' => $session->get('userID')), 'setting');
  [...]
}
```

and access it in JS:

```
var uid = Drupal.settings.CurrentCiviUid;
```

Answer (score 2):

For a Javascript-only solution, you can also make an API call using `user_contact_id` for the contact ID.  For instance:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => ["id"],
  'id' => "user_contact_id",
]);
```