# What is the contact ID of my own user record?

Tags: user-account, user-experience

Often, when giving support, it's helpful to direct people to their own record.  Is there a good way to find this?  As a dev, I can use the [techniques listed here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/get-current-contact-id), but I don't see a non-technical way to do this.  It doesn't seem to be listed on the User Dashboard, for instance.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal -> go to Hello [user] in the Toolbar -> then hit view contact Record (or view Contact Dashboard):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karin!  I should have specified that I know how to do this in Drupal - but often when giving community support (here or Mattermost) we don't know the CMS.  Is there a CMS-agnostic way to find this?