# Get Contact id from Relationship to use in a Hook

Tags: custom-fields, relationships, hooks

I want to display Contact B ID of a relationship for the current contact. I am building a hook and this is my code so far.

```
if ( $formName == 'CRM_Contactlayout_Form_Inline_ProfileBlock') {
        if ($form == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
            $ID= '190';
            $defaults['custom_189'] = $ID;
            $form->updateElementAttr('custom_189',array('readonly'));
    }
```

I want to replace 190 with a code that grabs the contact ID of that current users relationship.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: Is the "current user" the logged in contact, or the contact being viewed?  Which hook is this - looks like `buildForm`, but I can't be sure?  That will matter for getting the current user.  Finally - have you looked at API Explorer (**Support » Developer » API Explorer**)?  Ultimately you'll be using the `Relationship.get` API, and the API Explorer will generate the code you need.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech - I want to get the ID of the contact being viewed and i have used the API Explorer i got the code ready but i need the id of the contact being viewed.

Comment: See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3842/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
$contactId = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('cid', 'Positive');
```